# Chrome Extension Move Content On Page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am currently developing a chrome extension that requires putting a fixed iframe on the side of a tab. However, I am running into the issue of the iframe covering content on the page. Is there some code I could run in my content script that would move all the page content over and make room on the left side of the screen? (I don't want to actually change the chrome window width)

I have tried putting the current page in an iframe and having my iframe on the left, but then any input the user has done on the current page will be deleted. I have also tried using padding-left on the body of the current page, but that rarely works.

Is there a good way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: There's no magic method so you'll have to use the standard DOM/CSS. In some browsers extensions can use the sidebar API but Chrome doesn't have it. You can find the old answers, there should be plenty.

Comment: How would I use CSS to account for when the page uses javascript to set a elements width to screen.width?

Comment: There's no way to do it reliably.